# How to merge columns with similar name and sum up their numeric content in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with columns containing counts of observations for several populations (rows). Similar to the following, but biggest:

```
    df <- data.frame (pop = c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", "pop4","pop5"),
                  L1a  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L1b = c(4,2,5,0,0),
                  L1c = c(1,3,0,3,4),
                  L2a = c(0,3,1,2,0),
                  L2b = c(3,0,2,1,3)
    )
    df
```

So I need to merge the columns that are related (that share certain string in the column name, for example the string "L1") and sum up the counts into them. For the previous example a merged dataframe could be the following:

```
    df_merged <- data.frame (pop = c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", 
    pop4","pop5"),
                  L1  = c(5,5,5,4,6),
                  L2 = c(0,3,1,2,0)
    )
    df_merged
```

Another example would be the following dataframe:

```
    df <- data.frame (pop = c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", "pop4","pop5"),
                  L1a  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L1a2  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L1a2b  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L1a2b3  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L1b = c(4,2,5,0,0),
                  L1b1 = c(4,2,5,0,0),
                  L1b1b = c(4,2,5,0,0),
                  L1b1b10 = c(4,2,5,0,0),
                  L1c = c(1,3,0,3,4),
                  L2a = c(0,3,1,2,0),
                  L2a1d = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L2a1d2c = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L2b = c(3,0,2,1,3),
                  L3a3d  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3a3d3  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3f  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3f1a  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3f1a1  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3f1a1b  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3d3a  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
                  L3d3a3  = c(0,0,0,1,2)
    )
    df
```

Where let's say that I need to maintain all variables with less than four digits of code intact but I want to collapse all that have the first five digits of the name identical.
That should give the following result:

```
df_merged <- data.frame (pop = c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", 
"pop4","pop5"),
              L1a  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
              L1a2  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
              L1a2b  = c(0,0,0,2,4),
              L1b = c(4,2,5,0,0),
              L1b1 = c(4,2,5,0,0),
              L1b1b = c(8,4,10,0,0),
              L1c = c(1,3,0,3,4),
              L2a = c(0,3,1,2,0),
              L2a1d = c(0,0,0,2,4),
              L2b = c(3,0,2,1,3),
              L3a3d  = c(0,0,0,2,4),
              L3f  = c(0,0,0,1,2),
              L3f1a  = c(0,0,0,3,6)
)
df_merged
```

```
How could I do that?


I tried to find a post that could help me but there isn´t.
I´ll really appreciate your answer
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rowSums` on the columns that `starts_with` 'L1' in column names

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(L1 = rowSums(across(starts_with('L1'))), .keep = "unused", .after = pop)
```

-output

```
   pop L1 L2
1 pop1  5  0
2 pop2  5  3
3 pop3  5  1
4 pop4  4  2
5 pop5  6  0
```

---

If there are many such blocks of columns, use `split.default` to split into a list of common columns, do the `rowSums` by looping over the `list` (`map`) and then bind with the subset of original data

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
   split.default(str_remove(names(.), "[a-z]+$")) %>%
    map_dfc(rowSums, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    bind_cols(df %>% 
     select(-where(is.numeric)), .)
```

-output

```
    pop L1 L2
1 pop1  5  0
2 pop2  5  3
3 pop3  5  1
4 pop4  4  2
5 pop5  6  0
```

---

Or use `pivot_longer` to reshape to 'long' format before doing the group by `sum`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = ".value", 
      names_pattern = "(L\\d+).*") %>%
   group_by(pop) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  pop      L1    L2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 pop1      5     0
2 pop2      5     3
3 pop3      5     1
4 pop4      4     2
5 pop5      6     0
```

Comment: Thank you akrun! What if I have to do that for several groups of columns? Let's say that besides L1a, L1b, and L1c I also do have L2a, L2b, and L2c?

Comment: And if I need to recognize more complex variable names, like grouping L1a1, L1a2, L1a3 in one variable called L1a. I should modify the names_pattern argument, is this correct? Could you tell me how?

Comment: @Iriel if you can update your post with a new example with complex names that mimic your original data, it would be easier to help.  Otherwise, we don't know your use-case

Answer (score 0):

rowwise() with c_across() lets one apply arbitrary functions over the inputs , in this case sum()

```
df1 |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(L1=sum(c_across(contains("L1"))),
         .keep="unused",.after=pop) |> 
  ungroup()
```